# Подсчет цены на основании цены золота woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт продажи золотых украшений. Цена на золото скачет. Перерыл все, не нашел готовое решение для автоматического подсчета цены на основе курса золота, которое бы я ввел для определенных товаров или категорий.

К примеру вес изделия 3гр. х (цену за 1 гр. заданную в переменную).

Встречал ли кто-то похожий плагин или как это возможно сделать на PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать плагин [WooCommerce Gold Price Live](https://gold-feed.com/woocommerce-gold-price-live-plugin-extension.php).